# Fragment Container implementation with dynamic resizing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to implement two fragments, splitting the screen. But one of the fragments should have the ability to grow to full screen by pressing a button (and from full screen resize back to its original size).
All related posts are very old and point to deprecated android features.

Also, it is not clear to me if I need to resize the fragment container and the fragment itself, or just the fragment container.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, totally by accident find a much simpler way to achieve what I want.
More specifically, I had a ListView taking up half screen and wanted to grow it to full screen.

My first solution, far from optimal, was to just create a fragment with its own layout where the ListView occupies the whole screen. And created an enter animation, to grow the height from 0 to full height.
 This worked, but forced me to learn and implement DataViewModels, with LiveData, to be able to share seamlessly the ListView among the fragments.
Interesting, but way too complicated for what I wanted. Although it worked.

By chance, I discovered the layout views have this attribute:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

and just like that, with one line I got exactly what I wanted. I just chnged the LayoutParams of the ConstraintLayout, programatically:

```
protected void enterFullScreen() {
    rotateFAB(true);
    binding.fullScreenFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.to_normal_screen);

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params;
    params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) binding.displayResults.getLayoutParams();
    params.bottomToBottom = binding.main.getId();
    params.bottomToTop = -1;
    binding.displayResults.setLayoutParams(params);

}
```

and to restore the previous height:

```
protected void exitFullScreen() {
    rotateFAB(false);
    binding.fullScreenFab.setImageResource(R.drawable.to_full_screen);

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params;
    params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) binding.displayResults.getLayoutParams();
    params.bottomToBottom = -1;
    params.bottomToTop = binding.displayInput.getId();
    binding.displayResults.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

All within the same fragment, same ListView. Much Much simple than my first approach.